# My Login page in React isn't giving the output that I want

Tags: reactjs, authentication, event-handling

I am new to React and Javascript and one of the exercises that I was doing is to create a Login Page. When I give the username and password I want them to be displayed in the console the following way:

```
{username: "username", password: "password"}
```

Instead I am getting the following output:

```
{p:"p", pa:"pa", pas:"pas", pass:"pass",..., password:"password" , u:"u", us:"us", use:"use"..., username:"username" }
```

I am following the tutorials but I am getting that result. Can somebody help me spotting my error?

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Button, TextField} from '@material-ui/core';

export default function Login(){
  const [formState, setFormState] = useState({
      values:{}
    })
  };

  const handleChange = event => {
    event.persist();
    setFormState( formState => ({
      ...formState,
      values:{
        ...formState.values,
        [event.target.value]:event.target.value
      }
    }));   
  };
  
  const handleSubmit = event =>{
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(formState.values)
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <TextField
          label="Username"
          name="username"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value=formState.values.username
          ></TextField>
        <TextField
          label="Password"
          name="password"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value=formState.values.password
        ></TextField>
        <Button type="submit">Login</Button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your handle change is using `event.target.value` as key. You need to use the input's name which identifies your input box instead.
Change your handleChange like this -

```
  const handleChange = event => {
    event.persist();
    const values = { values: { ...formState.values, [event.target.name]:event.target.value}}; //name as key instead of value
    setFormState(values);   
  };
```

What I would recommend is structuring your state like this - `{username: "", password: ""};`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I also implemented the recommendation

Comment: @Javi That's awesome. Please vote and accept it as an answer if it helped you. :)